# Forms - Dropdownlist

Tags: html, forms, drop-down-menu

How to design a dropdown list that can have multiple selections using checkboxes. Can we do it using html/css or it requires javascript? For a visual clarity you can have a look at the image I have attached.
[image link](http://shivanand.in/tmp/dropdown.gif)

Comment: Seriously. Take off the image before this gets a lot of down votes. Describe the error, link the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with pure XHTML and/or only the  tag. The pane that opens up with all those checkboxes in the site you took a screeshot from, is actually a  that has an absolute position and that contains a list of checkboxes. So you'll need to write your own xhtml structure to achieve this. And will need to add some javascript to make it all work and interact.

Comment: Any website which provides a tutorial to create this kind of dropdown list?

Comment: Not really.  I'd suggest a peek at jQuery, see if it has something similar to what you want in the addons, then inspect it, or tweak one to make what you want.  As schnaader said, you can peek at exactly how they did it by viewing the source.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the HTML source code of the site on your screenshot. There it is done with Javascript. I doubt this is possible with pure HTML and I can't imagine a way to do this with CSS.